# Install few APK files on phone - different versions of the same app.

Tags: android, apk

I decided to have few versions of the same app on the phone. 
I clicked 'run' on first version of app in eclipse and apk was installed with the name: 'p2'. Then I changed package statement in Manifest to 'p5' , and changed all links in application classes and xmls, rebuilded app and clicked 'run' again to install next apk on the same phone.
To my astonishment I have two applications with name 'p2'. 
I expected to see 'p2' and 'p5'.
I was looking for an occurence of 'p2' in my code but there was no such place.
Can you guide me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the same application on the same device do followed steps:

- change Application package (where your main Activity is located)
- change Application Name (optional, doesn't seem good two equal names on the same device)

If you compile applications from Eclipse, you must change also `.project` file:

```
<projectDescription>
<name>Appl</name>
```

otherwise you can't import second application with the same name

Comment: This works for me. Thanks for your time, Maxim. Now I have different package name, app name and projectDescription and next version of my app has different name on the phone.